# Find and output longest string word c++

Tags: c++, string

I'm pretty new to programming and recently started working with strings. In my mind, this idea should somewhat work, but I have no idea what's wrong.

So I go through the string, with simb++ (to find length of the word) and where++ (to find where in the string am I) until I find a space, where I compare with the longest word I've found so so far (temp) and if it's longer, I make it the longest and find starting point of the word (start). When the for(...) ends, I write the word in the last for()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string sentence;
   string longest="";
   int simb=0;
   int temp=0;
   int where=0;
   int start=0;
   
  
   
   cout<<"Input sentence"<<endl;
   getline(cin,sentence);
   
   
   for(int i=0 ; i<sentence.size() ; i++)
   {

     if(sentence[i]!=' ')
     {
         simb++;
         where++;
     }
     
     if(sentence[i]==' ')
     {
         
        if(simb>temp)
        {
            where++;
            simb++;
            start=where-simb;
            temp=simb;
            
        }
        simb=0;
     }
   }
   
   for(int m=start ; m<=temp ; m++)
   {
       longest=longest+sentence[m];
   }
   
   cout<<"longest sentence"<<longest<<endl;
   
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can read whitespace-separated words with `>>` and save yourself plenty of headache.

Comment: I know you just started programming, but there is `std::istringstream` if you are required to read the entire line, or as noted `>>`  where both automatically do the checking for spaces.  Basically a 3 or 4 line solution.

Comment: `where` is (or probably should be, it isn't currently) the same as `i`, I think you can just get rid of `where`

Comment: Please be more specific than just saying that something is wrong. What are your inputs, and what happens that shouldn't (or doesn't happen that should)?

Comment: @molbdnilo makes sense. So the code works, haven't missed any ; or anything. After many tries, the best I can get is to output from e.g : 'I sleep good' something random like 'p goo'. I've probably messed something up with simb++ or where++ because I get a nonsense output.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Great! Will do, thanks!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Will do some research on istringstream, thank you!

Comment: @molbdnilo Can you give a hint on how to utilize >> ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues in your code:

1. if `simb<=temp` you don't increment `where`, you can just remove `where` completely and use `i` instead.
2. incrementing `simb` before calculating `start` results in `start` being 1 less than it should be
3. you don't check the length of last word in the string (assuming the string doesn't end with whitespace)
4. your final for loop goes from `start` to `temp` but should go from `start` to `start + temp`

Fixing these issues gives:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sentence;
    int simb = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int start = 0;

    string sentence = "test test2 test 3 test 4 foo longest";

    for (int i = 0; i <= sentence.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i != sentence.size() && sentence[i] != ' ')
        {
            simb++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (simb > temp)
            {
                start = i - simb;
                temp = simb;
            }
            simb = 0;
        }
    }

    string longest = "";
    for (int m = start; m < start + temp; m++)
    {
        longest = longest + sentence[m];
    }

    cout << "longest sentence: '" << longest << "'\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Note that using `std::istringstream` would be much simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string sentence = "test test2 test 3 test 4 foo longest";
    std::string longest;
    std::stringstream ss(sentence);
    std::string word;
    while (ss >> word)
    {
        if (word.length() > longest.length())
        {
            longest = word;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "longest sentence: '" << longest << "'\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, gained some string knowledge haha. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
1.first  locate where the spaces are.
2.calculate the gap between the two consequent words/strings.
3.find the word which has the maximum gap.
4.the world which has the maximum gap will be the longest one.

It's not c++ specific  you can try this with any language.
Here is the c++ example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
   //to get the user input
    cout<<"Enter a sentence:"<<endl;
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
   
   // here the old value refers to the last index having space
   // gap is the difference betweeen latest index having space and the old value
   // max stores the maximum gap
   int old=0;
   int max=0;
   int gap=0;
  
   //these two values store the starting and ending index of longest string 
   int startIndex;
   int endIndex;
   
  // This for loop determines the maximum gap and calculates the starting
  // and ending index of the longest word. 
   for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
       if(isspace(s[i])|| i==s.size()){
           if((i-old)>gap){
              max=(i-old);
              startIndex=i-max;
              endIndex=i;}

          gap=(i-old);
          old=i+1;}
      }

   cout<<"longest string in the sentence is:";
   //here we are using the determined starting and ending indices to print the longest word
   for(int i=startIndex;i<=endIndex;i++){
      cout<<s[i]; 
       }

  return 0;
  }
```